# disconnect user by name

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Disconnect user by his name.
It would look something like this:

```
@client.event
if (username == "username"):
    username.Disconnect()
```

I have nothing for now, so anything would be helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: first use Google to find some information.

Comment: at start you should find that class `User` has field `name` - see doc [User](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#user)

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like this:

```
async for member in guild.fetch_members(limit=150):
    if member.name == "username":
        await member.move_to(None)
```

Keep in mind that this is only for one guild.
If you want it done for all guilds that your bot can access, you could loop over them in this fashion:

```
for guild in guilds:
    [INSERT CODE SNIPPET ABOVE]
```